# java regular expression for String surrounded by ""

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have:

```
String s=" \"son of god\"\"cried out\" a good day and ok ";
```

This is shown on the screen as:

```
"son of god""cried out" a good day and ok 

Pattern phrasePattern=Pattern.compile("(\".*?\")");
Matcher m=phrasePattern.matcher(s);
```

I want get all the phrases surrounded by "" and add them to an `ArrayList<String>`. It might have more than 2 such phrases. How can I get each phrase and put into my `Arraylist`?

Comment: How are you going to handle the string `Then John said "I talked to Fred and he said 'I don't like it'"` ?

Comment: @JimGarrison it will be a even better question if you have a pair of double quotes inside of that pair of single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

With your `Matcher` you're 90% of the way there.  You just need the [`#find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) method.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
    list.add(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach, and I only suggest it because you did not explicitly say you must use regex matching, is to split on `"`. Every other piece is your interest.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] testCases = new String[] {
            " \"son of god\"\"cried out\" a good day and ok ",
            "\"starts with a quote\" and then \"forgot the end quote",
    };
    for (String testCase : testCases) {
        System.out.println("Input: " + testCase);
        String[] pieces = testCase.split("\"");
        System.out.println("Split into : " + pieces.length + " pieces");
        for (int i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
            if (i%2 == 1) {
                System.out.println(pieces[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Input:  "son of god""cried out" a good day and ok 
Split into : 5 pieces
son of god
cried out

Input: "starts with a quote" and then "forgot the end quote
Split into : 4 pieces
starts with a quote
forgot the end quote
```

If you want to ensure that there is an even number of double quotes, ensure the split result has an odd count.